# How to change icon in veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am trying to simulate V2x networks and i want to change icon for objects that aren't cars. I have tried with @display in .ned file but nothing happend in simulation?

Comment: A very important thing to note in this question is that this is wrt. modules that are dynamically instantiated by `TraCIScenarioManager` (not those statically created via entries in `.ned` files)

Answer (score 2):

The `@display` field is correct. Open the `network.ned` file, switch to the "Design" tab, right click the according module, select "Properties" and then the "Appearance" tab.

[image: OMNeT++ Property Window]

Answer (score 2):

I solved my issue by using the following code:

```
*.manager.moduleType = "bike=org.car2x.veins.nodes.Bike *=org.car2x.veins.nodes.Car" 
*.manager.moduleName = "bike=Bike *=node"  
*.manager.moduleDisplayString = "bike='i=veins/node/bicycle_vs' *='i=veins/node/car_vs'"
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to look out for is that properties in OMNeT++ are inherited, can be overridden, and sometimes (in the special case of `@display`) even their values are cascaded across the module and inheritance hierarchies.

So it might be a good idea to check the manual for these rules, so you can be sure that the value you change is not overridden somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you. I found the declaration in TraCIScenarioMenager.ned string moduleDisplayString = default("*='i=veins/node/car;is=vs'"); so i have to specify in .ini for the bikes only.  *.manager.moduleDisplayString = "Bike  *='i=veins/node/bicycle;is=vs'" (not really sure how to do that)